# dividing 2 doubles results always in 1 vb

Tags: vb.net, double, type-conversion, tryparse

both txtfield1 and txtMCLCCurrToEUR are doubles

(originally strings converted to double, both are the values of forex with 5 digits after decimal point)

```
Dim f1 As Double
txtField2.Text = (Double.TryParse(txtMCLCurrToEUR.Text, f1) / Double.TryParse(txtField1.Text, f1)).ToString("N5")
```

irrespective of their values, I always end up with 1 in the txtField2.text

I seem to have overlooked something essential, but for the life of me -- I don't see what it could be...

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Dude, have you considered adding another variable: `Dim f1, f2 as Double`???

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file.  You are attempting to divide by a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use f1 for both conversions, the second one would overwrite the first and the result is always one. 
Tryparse has no return value, only a flac vor succeed or not.

```
Dim f1 As Double
 Double.TryParse(txtMCLCurrToEUR.Text, f1)
Dim f2 As Double
 Double.TryParse(txtField1.Text, f2)
txtField2.Text =  (f1/f2 ).ToString("N5")
```

Comment: I don't know who marked you down, or why.  But good answer: you're entirely correct.

Comment: Ive made a mistake in the first version of my answer, the downvote was usefull to realise that ^^

Answer (score 1):

`Double.TryParse()` will return a `Boolean` value(true/false), `true` for success and `false` in case of failure of conversion from string to double.  so that if you apply division over Boolean values it will gives you result as either `1` or `0`.

You can realize this by running your program by enabling `Option Strict On`

consider one example:

```
 Dim a = True
 Dim b = True
 Dim c = CDbl(a) / CDbl(b) ' will gives you output as 1
```

Where as

```
 Dim a = True
 Dim b = False
 Dim c = CDbl(a) / CDbl(b) ' will gives you output as -1.#INF
```

Simply you can do this without using any third variable, like the following.

```
txtField2.Text = (Val(txtMCLCurrToEUR.Text) / Val(txtField1.Text)).ToString("N5")
```

`Val()` will return `0` in case it failed to convert the input string/null

Comment: very nice!  you guys are the greatest!  Thank you all for the elegant solutions!